# Variable Not Defined Compiler Error

Tags: vba, compiler-errors

I am a long time avid Excel user but am just starting to learn VBA. I am using the following code but am getting an error when I try to run `Sub test`:

> Compile Error:Variable not defined

Can you help me figure out what is wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Function toFarenheit(degrees)
    toFarenheit = (9 / 5) * degrees + 32
End Function

Function toCentigrade(degrees)
    toCentigrade = (5 / 9) * degrees - 32
End Function

Sub test()
    answer = toCentigrade(55)
    MsgBox answer    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

You have `Option Explicit` turn on which means you *must* declare your variables before using them.

In `Sub test`, you are missing a declaration for `answer`. Adding this should fix it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim answer As Variant
    answer = toCentigrade(55)
    MsgBox answer    
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

Since you are new to VBA, you might want to consider typing both your variables and function returns. You don't have to do this (and everything will be treated as a `Variant`), but it is good practice.

If you type everything properly, your example would become:

```
Option Explicit

' Accept a double value and return a double type value.
Function toFarenheit(degrees As Double) As Double
    toFarenheit = (9 / 5) * degrees + 32
End Function

Function toCentigrade(degrees As Double) As Double
    toCentigrade = (5 / 9) * degrees - 32
End Function

Sub test()
    ' Variable type matches what the function will return.
    Dim answer As Double
    answer = toCentigrade(55)
    MsgBox answer    
End Sub
```

Comment: I would add that the custom Functions should be `toWhatever(degrees As Long) As Long` or whatever variable type you want. (not required but is always helpful to define variable type)

Comment: @Chrismas007 - I would agree. In the example provided by the OP, no type is defined for function return (which will return a `Variant` in Excel VBA) which is why I used `Variant` in my example.

Comment: @Chrismas007 - I updated the answer to include typing. This would be good info for someone new to VBA to consider anyway. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

I tested this to convert to farenheit

The function is as follows

```
Function ToFarenheit(Degrees As Double)

ToFarenheit = (9 / 5) * Degrees + 32

End Function
```

The sub is as follows

```
Sub TestFunction()

MsgBox ToFarenheit(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem... The issue is that `answer` is a non-defined variable under `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score -3):

Don't listen to the professionals. The answer for the ordinary person is: remove statement "option explicit", probably at the top somewhere. Easy, and correct for you and me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35108706)