# Copy and paste a dynamically variable column with values from one worksheet into another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to copy and paste a column from a data output from one worksheet entitled *ImportTXT* into a table in another worksheet entitled *ExtractData*, but this column can be dynamic and the number of points can change (That is, how many point numbers there are (1,2,3,...) and also how many iterations of each point (in this case, there are 9 point 1's, 9 point 2's, 9 point 3's, etc.)). That means the code should work for any similar type file but of variable size.

Here are some photos for reference:

The first image shows what the data looks like from the *ImportTXT* sheet. For reference, the first cell will always be in cell "A51".

[Data in ImportTXT column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjyti.png)

The second image shows my goal for the look of the table in the "ExportData" sheet. The first cell in which the data should be pasted will always be "C8".

[Final appearance of column in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZatQT.png)

Here is a macro that I have recorded to try and select all of the numbers only in the Point No. column:

```
Sub SelectPointNoCol()
'
' SelectPointNoCol Macro
' Selects Point No Column and pastes it in the corresponding column in the table.

    Sheets("ImportTXT").Select
    Range("A51").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ExtractData").Select
    Range("C8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this selection method is giving me a runtime error and I am not sure how to fix it. After running through the code one by one, it looks like on my computer the `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select` code is not doing its job of only selecting the Point No. column. My process was this: Select cell A51 in the *ImportTXT* sheet, select Ctrl+Shift+End, then Ctrl+Shift+ left arrow (<--) twice, then under the Home tab click Find&Select, GoToSpecial, check "constants", then copy and paste the numbers under the PointNo column in the *ExtractData* sheet.

Note: *The Point No. doesn't exactly relate to the rest of the data, it's just a marker and could also be a letter such as A, B, C, etc. but numbers have just been used.*

Thx in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Your question isn't exactly clear about the issue you are facing. How does the rest of the data in `ExtractData` relate to the data in `ImportTXT`? Are you just copying data from `ImportTXT` to `ExtractData`? We need to know how the `point` data relates to the rest of the data in `ExtractData`.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the main question if that helps to clarify your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matcha22 Ok, if the numbers from `ImportTXT` don't really relate to the rest of the data in `ExtractData` and you just want the list of numbers in order with the spaces removed you don't need to use VBA to do it, you can just copy/paste the numbers and then sort the values to remove the blank rows.

Here's how you do that:

[image]

Now, if you want that to automatically happen without copying and pasting the values manually, that would require VBA.

EDIT: @Matcha22 based off of your updates to your original post, I gather that you want to have this happen automatically which would require VBA code.

I came up with some code that will do this for you, here is a breakdown of what it does:

1. starts at a defined starting point in `ImportTxt`
2. goes down from that starting point and finds the cell that contains the last value in the list to be copied and pasted to `ExtractData`. This is defined as the first row in the column that is followed by 2 rows where the value is blank. (your values for `Point No.` are listed every other row so the last value will be followed by 2 rows that are blank instead of just 1)
3. takes that range and copies it
4. pastes the values into `ExtractData` where you define for it to be pasted
5. sorts on the values to remove the blank rows

for the code you need to define the column and row you want to start at in `ImportTxt` as well as the column and row you want to paste the results into in `ExtractData`

Here's the code, it should work for you:

```
    Dim ImportTxtRowNumStart As Integer
    Dim ImportTxtRowNumEnd As Integer
    Dim foundTargetRow As Boolean
    Dim ImportTxtCol As String

    foundTargetRow = False

    ImportTxtCol = "A" ' the column in ImportTxt where Point No is
    ImportTxtRowNumStart = 51 ' the row in ImportTxt where Point No starts
    ImportTxtRowNumEnd = ImportTxtRowNumStart

    Do
        If Sheets("ImportTXT").Range(ImportTxtCol + CStr((ImportTxtRowNumEnd + 1))).Value = "" And Sheets("ImportTXT").Range(ImportTxtCol + CStr((ImportTxtRowNumEnd + 2))).Value = "" Then
            foundTargetRow = True
        Else
            ImportTxtRowNumEnd = ImportTxtRowNumEnd + 1
        End If
    Loop While foundTargetRow = False


   Dim ExportDataColumn As String
   Dim ExportDataRow As Integer

   ExportDataColumn = "C" ' the column in ExportData where values go
   ExportDataRow = 8 ' the row in ExportData where values go

   Range(ImportTxtCol + CStr(ImportTxtRowNumStart) + ":" + ImportTxtCol + CStr(ImportTxtRowNumEnd)).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("ExtractData").Select
   Range(ExportDataColumn + CStr(ExportDataRow)).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExtractData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExtractData").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(ExportDataColumn + CStr(ExportDataRow)), _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExtractData").Sort
       .SetRange Range(ExportDataColumn + CStr(ExportDataRow) + ":" + ExportDataColumn + CStr(ExportDataRow + (ImportTxtRowNumEnd - ImportTxtRowNumStart)))
       .Header = xlNo
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
   End With
```

Here's what it looks like when it runs:

[image]

If this doesn't work of if you have other questions about how to implement this please let me know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! This process works as well, but the problem is when I try to select the Point No. column in a way in which it doesn't matter how many points there are (the code is in the updated question :), the Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select part of the code does not do its job of eventually only selecting that first column. It selects that column as well as the rest of the data, which then messes up the rest of the code. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Thank you very much this is great! I'm sure it works, however my VBA is set to *option explicit* and I get some warning messages that some variables are not defined. I apologize if it's too much of a hassle, but do you know which variables you did not define and what type (Boolean, String, etc.) they need to be defined as so that I can add that to the Dim portion of the code? Thanks!

Comment: @Matcha22 what exactly does the error message say? I declared all of the variables I used before they were used, so I don't think your warning messages are coming from the code I provided. It probably has to do with how you are using the code. Look at this post that talks more about option explicit and variables not being defined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694994/variable-not-defined-compiler-error

Comment: it gives me the same *Compile Error:Variable not defined* as in the link you shared in the previous comment. I try and run it line-by-line (F8) but the code doesn't let me run a single line of it. I think the problem may be that the variable ImportTxtRowNumEnd variable is implicitly defined (I'm referring to the row right below your first block of Dim's). That variable is highlighted in blue after the compile error message pops up. I may be wrong about that being the cause however. What do you think?

Comment: @Matcha22 you're right, I was making revisions to the code and I didn't change the variable name to the correct value when it is being declared. I changed the code in my answer, now it should run without warnings. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes! That problem is resolved, however I get another message *run time error 1004 range of object _global failed* and the debugger points to this line of code *Range(ImportTxtCol + CStr(ImportTxtRowNumStart) + ":" + ImportTxtCol + CStr(ImportTxtRowNumEnd)).Select*. Do you know what the problem could be? I apologize for the inconvenience :(

Comment: @Matcha22 sorry for all of the confusion. I think the problem was due to the fact that this line `ImportTxtRowNumEnd = ImportTxtRowNumStart` was put before `ImportTxtRowNumStart` was being set. I corrected the answer again and now it should not give you any more errors (knock on wood). let me know if you still have issues with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works now!!! :) I just added two lines right after your first Dim block before the code actually begins: *Sheets("ImportTXT").Select
    Range("A51").Select* so that it automatically selects cell "A51". This is because if that was not there, I would have to physically click the cell (probably as you intended to) or else the final result would be blank. However now it works for me and so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Matcha22 Awesome! glad I could help.